# Select records where fields in t1 don't exist in t2, but ignoring if t1 fields are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tricky one.
I have two sets on tables

Table 1:

```
VoucherCode | Category  | Size  | Colour | Gender
0001        | Shirt     | NULL  | Green  | Male
0002        | Shirt     | 12    | NULL   | Male
0003        | Shirt     | 12    | Blue   | NULL
0004        | Shirt     | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  
0005        | Shorts    | NULL  | Brown  | Male
0006        | Shorts    | 10    | NULL   | Male
0007        | Shorts    | 12    | Green  | NULL
0008        | Shorts    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL
0009        | Pants     | NULL  | Pink   | Female
0010        | Pants     | 10    | NULL   | Male
0011        | Pants     | 12    | Purple | NULL
0012        | Pants     | NULL  | NULL   | NULL
```

Table 2:

```
ProductCode | Category  | Size  | Colour | Gender
0001        | Shirt     | 10    | Blue   | Male
0002        | Shorts    | 13    | Brown  | Female
0003        | Pants     | 10    | Purple | Male
0004        | Pants     | 10    | Purple | Female
```

The first table is a list vouchers, the second table is a list of products.
I need to write a query that will return a list of vouchers, that couldn't possibly work.

The premise, certain attributes of a voucher can be `NULL` in place of a literal, this is because the intended use of that voucher is for any combination of the other attributes which are defined.

Examples:

VoucherCode 0001 **couldn't** work because there are no products with a Category of Shirt, Colour of Green, and Gender of Male

VoucherCode 0004 **could** work because there are is a product with a Category of Shirt.

Taking this into account, I need to write a query to return all the records from Table 1 that could not possibly work.

Results to look like this

```
VoucherCode | Category  | Size  | Colour | Gender
0001        | Shirt     | NULL  | Green  | Male
0002        | Shirt     | 12    | NULL   | Male
0003        | Shirt     | 12    | Blue   | NULL
0005        | Shorts    | NULL  | Brown  | Male
0006        | Shorts    | 10    | NULL   | Male
0007        | Shorts    | 12    | Green  | NULL
0009        | Pants     | NULL  | Pink   | Female
0011        | Pants     | 12    | Purple | NULL
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Write down the rules, the predicates or expressions that each voucher must satisfy to be included in the output. examples are helpful, but the rules need to be defined first.

Comment: Your description is *almost* perfect. But you seem to have forgotten to list the vouchers 3,4 and 8 in your table t1. They only appear in your solution.

Comment: I noticed my mix ups in the examples, I've cleared it up ... hopefully it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using left join with is null.

Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @Voucher as TABLE
(
    VoucherCode char(4), 
    Category varchar(10),
    Size int, 
    Colour varchar(10),
    Gender varchar(6)    
)

INSERT INTO @Voucher VALUES

('0001', 'Shirt', NULL, 'Green', 'Male'),
('0002', 'Shirt', 12  , NULL, 'Male'),
('0003', 'Shirt', 12  , 'Blue', NULL),
('0004', 'Shirt', NULL, NULL, NULL ), 
('0005', 'Shorts', NULL, 'Brown', 'Male'),
('0006', 'Shorts', 10  , NULL, 'Male'),
('0007', 'Shorts', 12  , 'Green', NULL),
('0008', 'Shorts', NULL, NULL, NULL),
('0009', 'Pants', NULL, 'Pink', 'Female'),
('0010', 'Pants', 10  , NULL, 'Male'),
('0011', 'Pants', 12  , 'Purple', NULL),
('0012', 'Pants', NULL, NULL, NULL)


DECLARE @Product as TABLE
(
    ProductCode char(4), 
    Category varchar(10),
    Size int, 
    Colour varchar(10),
    Gender varchar(6)    
)

INSERT INTO @Product VALUES
('0001', 'Shirt', 10, 'Blue', 'Male'),
('0002', 'Shorts', 13, 'Brown', 'Female'),
('0003', 'Pants', 10, 'Purple', 'Male'),
('0004', 'Pants', 10, 'Purple', 'Female')
```

**The Query:**

```
SELECT  V.VoucherCode,
        V.Category, 
        V.Size, 
        V.Colour, 
        V.Gender
FROM @Voucher V
LEFT JOIN @Product P
ON V.Category = P.Category
AND ISNULL(V.Size, P.Size) = P.Size
AND ISNULL(V.Colour, P.Colour) = P.Colour
AND ISNULL(V.Gender, P.Gender) = P.Gender
WHERE P.ProductCode IS NULL
```

Results:

```
VoucherCode Category    Size    Colour  Gender
0001        Shirt       NULL    Green   Male
0002        Shirt       12      NULL    Male
0003        Shirt       12      Blue    NULL
0005        Shorts      NULL    Brown   Male
0006        Shorts      10      NULL    Male
0007        Shorts      12      Green   NULL
0009        Pants       NULL    Pink    Female
0011        Pants       12      Purple  NULL
```

Comment: I was actually just about to start typing up exactly what you just did ... I will do that in future ... That's awesome :) Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a solution to get your result (but I didn't test it)

```
SELECT v.*
FROM Vouchers AS v
  LEFT OUTER  JOIN Products AS p
    ON v.Category = p.category AND 
       ISNULL(v.Size, -1) = ISNULL(p.Size, -1) AND 
       ISNULL(v.Colour, '-1') = ISNULL(p.Colour, '-1') AND 
       ISNULL(v.Gender, '-1') = ISNULL(p.Gender, '-1')
WHERE p.ProductCode IS NULL
```

Comment: After your clearance of example data, this code sample wouldn't work.